# Replacing a character in a string when it is single

Tags: java, string

Using java how can I replace a character in a string ONLY when it occurs single?

ex:
Replace single `*` with a `#`

input string:

```
a*b**c*d***e
```

output string:

```
a#b**c#d***e
```

`inputString.replaceAll("*", "#");`  replaces all the `*s` and returns `a#b##c#d###e`

Comment: Use inputString.replaceAll(correctRegex, "#")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [negative lookahead and lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
String s = "a*b**c*d***e";
String r = s.replaceAll("(?<!\\*)\\*(?!\\*)", "#"); // a#b**c#d***e
```

This reads: "an * not preceeded by an * and not followed by an *" (note the fact that `*` must be escaped in a regular expression, as it is a meta character).

Answer (score -1):

Try using the charAt(n) method, setting the number n (the parameter) as the number of the * single ones, and then set the string to the "#" and see if that helps.

Comment: This Answer is unhelpful.  You can't "set" a character in a String in Java.  Java Strings are immutable.